# Javascript click eventlistener not working in blazor

Tags: javascript, css, blazor

I'm relatively new to all of this so hopefully this is a reasonably simple question! I have the following code that was working perfectly previously with pure HTML/CSS.  It changes the CSS Class of an element when you click another element:

```
<script>
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
    const close = document.querySelector('.close')
    const nav = document.querySelector('nav')
    
    menu.addEventListener('click',() =>{
        nav.classList.add('open-nav')
    })
    
    close.addEventListener('click',() =>{
        nav.classList.remove('open-nav')
    })
    </script>
```

However, I'm working with a friend and we're trying to convert the site to use the Microsoft Blazor framework.  We've done that largely successfully and re-structured the site slightly so that the header and footer of the site are loaded from a shared "layout" page, and an @body tag in the middle pulls in that particular pages main content. The stylesheet links and the script above are stored in another, separate layout file.

I'm reasonably certain its all linking together properly as the stylesheets are getting applied properly, and the javascript is in the same place as the stylesheet definitions.

However, the Javascript no longer works with everything in Blazor. There are no errors in my browser dev tools, but the style of the nav element simply does not change when I click the .menu element any more.

Is there anything specific to be done in Blazor to allow running of Javascript? How would I even begin to debug if the Javascript is trying to do anything?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try wrapping that whole snippet with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    /* PLACE THAT SNIPPET HERE */
}, false);`

Comment: If this is your javascript there is no need to use it in Blazor. This is the wrong approach. Think of Blazor as rendering HTML not manipulating it after its rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not be manipulating the Browser DOM outside of Blazor. You quickly get the Browser DOM and Blazor DOM out of sync which causes unexpected render results.

There are several ways to hide/show elements in Blazor.  As you've provided little context as to what Nav is, here are a couple of ways of showing/hiding a typical component/code block:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" @onclick=OpenMenu1>
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        @if (this.DropdownOpen1)
        {
            <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" @onclick=OpenMenu2>
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu @this.ShowMenu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool DropdownOpen1;
    private bool DropdownOpen2;

    private string ShowMenu
        => this.DropdownOpen2
            ? "show"
            : string.Empty;

    private void OpenMenu1()
        => DropdownOpen1 = !DropdownOpen1;

    private void OpenMenu2()
        => DropdownOpen2 = !DropdownOpen2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use Blazor server then you should put all scripts before the below line in the `<body>` tag in end of `_Host.cshtml` or `_Layout.cshtml` according to the version that you use:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Second, you have to call the javascripts method in the `OnAfterRender` or `OnAfterRenderAsync` such as below:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("YourJavascriptMethodName");
        }
    }
```

> OnAfterRender and OnAfterRenderAsync are called after a component has finished rendering. Element and component references are populated at this point. Use this stage to perform additional initialization steps with the rendered content, such as JS interop calls that interact with the rendered DOM elements.

For more info you can refer to [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [After component render (OnAfterRender{Async})](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync)